# OpenDocument export in LyX with LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, lyx, luatex

I am writing in LyX a document using Georgia fonts, and tried to save it as Word via ODT. If I choose to enable "Use non-Tex fonts", I cannot save from LyX as OpenDocument. That is, the output option turns grey. If I disable it, I lose Georgia. Surely, something can be improvised by converting LuaTeX's PDF output, but at that point, there will be so many extraneous characters, that I'd rather write the document by hand.

Is there no simple way to write with Georgia and still use OpenDocument output?

Comment: Can't you just export without the custom fonts and then edit the resulting `.odt` file?

Comment: LyX use `tex4ht` to convert to `odt` and it doesn't support open type fonts, so this is not possible. Converted document doesn't contain font information anyway, so result will be same regardless of used font.

Comment: @JosephWright: I need a Word file for those who don't accept anything except Word, and I need a PDF for the rest of the world.

Comment: @NickSandor Yes, but all that seems necessary is (1) Work the way you want, (2) Save PDF, (3) Alter font setup in LyX, (4) Export `.odt`, (5) Revert LyX file, (6) Change font in Word.

Comment: Perhaps write in latex rather than lyx and use http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/ to convert to rich text format, then convert to whatever.  In my limited experience the more complex the task the more likely there is an already existing latex solution rather than one that works with lyx.

Comment: Note: it seems pdflatex also doesn't like the non-TeX fonts option, so to get PDF you might need to use one of the other converters.